# How to generate 2 pairs of random numbers 100 times.

Tags: python, random, range

I have two variables which I have assigned to be random numbers like below:

```
x = random.randrange(1, 100)
n = random.randrange(1, 100)
```

These variables are then used to calculate x^n which I have written code for in another function. However instead of producing one random number for x and one random number for n I need to produce 100 random numbers for each and then run them through the loop that calculates x^n for all 100 numbers. I'm not sure on how to produce 100 random numbers for x and n while still keeping their variables the same.

Comment: `foo = [(random.randrange(1, 100), random.randrange(1, 100)) for _ in range(100)]; for x, n in foo: ...` ?

Comment: Also why not compute `x` and `n` inside of your loop?

Comment: With Python 3.6 use `random.choices(range(100))`

Comment: if you have a function like `power(x,n): return x**n` and you want to feed it with a list of `ns` and a list of `xs` you can just do: `for i in range(100): result.append(power(xs[i],ns[i]))`

Comment: i dont understand, do you need x and n pairs to be the same sequence or not?, like `x[0] == n[0]...x[y] == n[y]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly build a list with your 100 values by using a list comprehension:

```
[(random.randrange(1, 100), random.randrange(1, 100)) for _ in range(100)]
```

The produced list holds 100 couples of randomly generated values.

This is nothing more than a condesate version of the following:

```
tuplesList = []
for _ in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(1, 100)
    n = random.randrange(1, 100)
    tuplesList.append(x, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to create list of tuples

```
for x,n in zip(random.sample(range(1,101),100), random.sample(range(1,101),100)):
    #code using x and n
```

Comment: `random.sample` is not equivalent, it is without replacement, you need `random.choices` if you have Python 3.6

Comment: @Chris_Rands Sorry didn't understand. OP need 100 random numbers for both and loop through it. Here `sample` do same thing in py2 and py3. `zip` will return `zip object`  in py3 which is an iterable.

Comment: `random.sample` can never output the same item from a list/object twice (i.e. no replacement), unlike `random.choices`, which is new in Py 3.6

Comment: I am not trying to output the same item from a list/object twice. Instead different in each sequence.

Comment: Maybe you don't  understand the difference between sampling with and without replacement; read about  sample and choices in the docs